# Política de qualidade ou política da qualidade

Tags: concordância

Qual seria a formulação correta "De qualidade" ou "Da qualidade"?

O mesmo vale para frases como “política `da` segurança e privacidade” e “política `da` garantia” ou ainda “termos e condições `da` compra”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em geral o `de`, sem artigo, é preferível, enquanto que o artigo às vezes é usado quando se deseja denotar especificidade. Por exemplo:

> pele **de** urso"

é uma pele de um dado tipo - de urso e não de tigre, e

> "pele **do** urso

pode se referir a pele de um dado urso, não de um qualquer.

Similarmente, em "recibo **de** compra", o `de compra` caracteriza o tipo de documento, enquanto "recibo **da** compra", se referirá usualmente ao recibo de uma compra específica e se poderia também dizer "*recibo de compra da compra (do computador)*". A forma abreviada é coloquial em alguns casos, e há até expressões em que o uso do artigo chega a ser incorreto:

> Não consigo achar o *'recibo **de** compra e venda'* da venda do terreno.
>   *Não consigo achar o *'recibo **da** compra e venda'* do terreno.

Isso é especialmente verdade em expressões fixas como `risco de morte`, `qualidade de vida`, etc. E também se aplica às expressões da pergunta: "política **de** segurança e privacidade" e "política **de** garantia" ou ainda "termos e condições **de** compra".

Um último exemplo, que torna claro o deslocamento da ênfase que o artigo pode trazer, inclusive podendo alterar completamente o significado da expressão:

> Política **de** ciência

se refere usualmente ao posicionamento do estado com relação à ciência, especialmente seu financiamento público. Enquanto

> Política **da** ciência

se refere ao aspecto político da atividade social que é o fazer da ciência.